# How to add beta tester to developer console,when i will get Opt -In URl

Tags: android, google-play

Can anyone guide me the whole steps required for creating beta tester group and how to add them as tester on developer console, how can i get link,
i have gone through some posts as i am doing it for very first time,

it will be helpful if anyone can  tell me steps required to get it done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To add new Google group for Beta testing**

1) go to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview

2) Select create group and fill the all the details such as Group name,Group email address etc.

3) If you want to add a new tester to existing group go to -> manage -> memebers -> direct add members

If you  want to send email to group member or individual follow below steps:

4) On left panel you will find recently viewed group OR My groups click them

5) For eg. tester_group click on the group -> on top bar find new topic -> click it

6) you can send email on behalf of group or by your play store email id

7) new window will open write your message select type of post as 
    -> start discussion    (Two way process) 
    -> make an announcement (one way process)
8) and then select post message will be delivered to all members of group.

**To Add testers On Play Store**

1) go to beta testing tab before uploading new apk for beta

2) select Testing option as 
    -> Beta testing using google groups or google+ communities

3) add google group by typing group name in EditBox then select add button

4) your google group now has been added as tester for the app.

5) now upload the apk and rollout from manage release page

6) in few hours  you will get Opt -In URl which is link for beta testers to install app from playstore

**Note:** 
   if you have added google tester group after publishing the app,then this group will not be saved.

As tester group and you have to add it again and again (wont serve any purpose).

so make sure,you add google group before uploading and publishing new apk.

so that after getting Opt -In URl link your group will be able to install the app from playstore.

Hope this helps you :)